# C# Parsing Excel custom cell format

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, parsing

I am parsing an Excel file and am having difficulty reading in the value of a cell that has a custom cell format of `dd mmm yy`.  The value in the cell in question is 29 Oct 09 (cell B25).  When I run

```
String arrive = Convert.ToString(_worksheets["GENERAL"].get_Range("B25", Type.Missing).Value2);
```

I get "40114" as the cell's value.

Then when I try

```
DateTime arrive = Convert.ToDateTime(_worksheets["GENERAL"].get_Range("B25", Type.Missing).Value2);
```

I get an error stating "When casting from a number the value must be a number less than infinity."

Any thoughts ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You either a) need to know how excel represents dates and have a function to convert that representation (40114) into a date (assuming you can't do that directly) or b) pull the contents of the cell as a formatted string and use Noldorin's answer. The latter may be easier, the former is almost certainly better (safer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That random number is an OLE date.

You probably want the `DateTime.FromOADate` method. Have a look at the [reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you want the [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method, since this is a non-standard format you're working with, as far as .NET is concerned.

Try the following:

```
var dateTimeStr = _worksheets["GENERAL"].get_Range("B25", Type.Missing).Value2);
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeStr, "dd MMM yy");
```

The [MSDN Custom Date and Time Frormat Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) page may also be a good reference to bookmark.

Comment: Without wishing to be difficult, that's not going to work terribly well converting 40114... I agree that if he could guaranteeably pull the value in the specified format it would work

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  When I tried the suggestion I received an error stating that ParseExact takes 2 arguments.  I guess this is where I state this is the first time I have ever coded anything in C# and apologize profusely for my noobness.